# Protect app internal folder from users in android

Tags: android, encryption, data-protection

How to provide security to data which were stored in app internal folder by restricting user to open it  even if the device is rooted,
One method i have encountered AES Encryption but i want to know is their way we can do this to a folder or can we create a file in which we can access necessary image or pdf which were downloaded and stay far reach from end user.